# Swift 3 Find the right index of an [Int] array with duplicate values

Tags: swift

i looking for a way to find the right index of an [int]-array with duplicate values. I want to recognize that the value in a loop has change. A loop-counter-varibale is not possible because the evaluation is in another thread.

```
var arrayInt = [1,2,2,3]
var arrayIndex : Int?
var currentStep = 0

for i in arrayInt
{
    arrayIndex = arrayInt.index(of: i)
    print("Index \(arrayIndex)")
    currentStep += 1 // Is not possible

    for numbers in 1...i{

         DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1 + currentStep)) {
             // prints always "4" becauses its at the executen time the value "4", which is plausible
             print("CurrentStep \(currentStep)")
         }
     }
}
//Prints:
//Index Optional(0)
//Index Optional(1)
//Index Optional(1) // must be 2
//Index Optional(3)
```

Solve by Gerriet:

```
var arrayInt = [1,2,2,3]
var currentStep = 0

for (currentStep,i) in arrayInt.enumerated(){
  for numbers in 1...i{
     DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1 + currentStep)) {
        print("CurrentStep \(currentStep)")
     }
  } 
}
//Prints:
//CurrentStep Optional(0)
//CurrentStep Optional(1)
//CurrentStep Optional(2)
//CurrentStep Optional(3)
```

Comment: What are you mean? finding indexs of a duplicate value of array? right?

Comment: Not sure, I understand, but I think you can achieve it with enumerated: `for (index,value) in arrayInt.enumerated() {
    print("Index \(index) : \(value)")
}` . That way you get the correct index right away (independent of duplicates).

Comment: How simple and it works! Thank u

Comment: I put my comment into an answer, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my comment as an answer. You can achieve it with enumerated:

```
for (index,value) in arrayInt.enumerated() { 
    print("Index \(index) : \(value)") 
}
```

That way you get the correct index right away (independent of duplicates).

Answer (score -1):

Hey Try below code will work for you:

```
    var arrayInt = [1,2,2,3]
    var arrayIndex : Int?
    var currentStep = 0

    for i in 0..<arrayInt.count{
        //here i is Your index 
        arrayIndex = i
        print("Index \(arrayIndex)")
        currentStep += 1 // Is not possible

        for numbers in 1...arrayInt[i]{

            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1 + currentStep)) {
                // prints always "4" becauses its at the executen time the value "4", which is plausible
                print("CurrentStep \(currentStep)")
            }
        }
    }
```